# Keycloak doesn't start with error WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration

Tags: wildfly, keycloak

I just installed the last version of Keycloak (3.4.3), and everything seems ok but it doesn't start because of an error of type :

```
WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
```

I use keycloak for more than a year (version 2.5.1 until now) and I never had this kind of problem.
Moreover, I was able to upgrade my Keycloak without any problem, but here I make a fresh installation and I got this error.

The full log of the start is hereunder :

```
Calling "E:\backend\keycloak\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
Setting JAVA property to "E:\backend\jdk\bin\java"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: "E:\backend\keycloak"

  JAVA: "E:\backend\jdk\bin\java"

  JAVA_OPTS: "-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.log.dir=E:\backend\logs\keycloak"

===============================================================================

10:05:11,459 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.1.Final
10:05:11,656 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.7.SP1
10:05:11,771 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0049: Keycloak 3.4.3.Final (WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final) starting
10:05:12,619 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) OPVDX002: Failed to pretty print validation error: null
10:05:12,620 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:143) [wildfly-controller-3.0.8.Final.jar:3.0.8.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:387) [wildfly-server-3.0.8.Final.jar:3.0.8.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:370) [wildfly-controller-3.0.8.Final.jar:3.0.8.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module org.jboss.as.ejb3
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.parseExtensions(ExtensionXml.java:154) [wildfly-controller-3.0.8.Final.jar:3.0.8.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml$DefaultExtensionHandler.parseExtensions(StandaloneXml.java:131) [wildfly-server-3.0.8.Final.jar:3.0.8.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_5.readServerElement(StandaloneXml_5.java:219) [wildfly-server-3.0.8.Final.jar:3.0.8.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml_5.readElement(StandaloneXml_5.java:142) [wildfly-server-3.0.8.Final.jar:3.0.8.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:107) [wildfly-server-3.0.8.Final.jar:3.0.8.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:49) [wildfly-server-3.0.8.Final.jar:3.0.8.Final]
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:122) [staxmapper-1.3.0.Final.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:76) [staxmapper-1.3.0.Final.jar:1.3.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:126) [wildfly-controller-3.0.8.Final.jar:3.0.8.Final]
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.parseExtensions(ExtensionXml.java:146) [wildfly-controller-3.0.8.Final.jar:3.0.8.Final]
        ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.loadModule(ExtensionXml.java:195) [wildfly-controller-3.0.8.Final.jar:3.0.8.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.access$000(ExtensionXml.java:68) [wildfly-controller-3.0.8.Final.jar:3.0.8.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml$1.call(ExtensionXml.java:126) [wildfly-controller-3.0.8.Final.jar:3.0.8.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml$1.call(ExtensionXml.java:123) [wildfly-controller-3.0.8.Final.jar:3.0.8.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320) [jboss-threads-2.2.1.Final.jar:2.2.1.Final]
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Error loading module from E:\backend\keycloak\modules\system\layers\base\org\wildfly\discovery\main\module.xml
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:228)
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:204)
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:170)
        at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleFinder.lambda$findModule$3(LocalModuleFinder.java:149) [jboss-modules.jar:1.5.1.Final]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_102]
        at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleFinder.findModule(LocalModuleFinder.java:144) [jboss-modules.jar:1.5.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.findModule(ModuleLoader.java:439) [jboss-modules.jar:1.5.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModuleLocal(ModuleLoader.java:342) [jboss-modules.jar:1.5.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:289) [jboss-modules.jar:1.5.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1078) [jboss-modules.jar:1.5.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1448) [jboss-modules.jar:1.5.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1476) [jboss-modules.jar:1.5.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:225) [jboss-modules.jar:1.5.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.loadModule(ExtensionXml.java:177) [wildfly-controller-3.0.8.Final.jar:3.0.8.Final]
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.xml.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected content of type 'element start' named 'properties', text is: '<properties>' (position: START_TAG seen ...n:jboss:module:1.6" name="org.wildfly.discovery">\n    <properties>... @26:17)
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.unexpectedContent(ModuleXmlParser.java:257)
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.validateNamespace(ModuleXmlParser.java:310)
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleContents(ModuleXmlParser.java:525)
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseDocument(ModuleXmlParser.java:340)
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:226)
        ... 21 more

10:05:12,625 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
10:05:12,664 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0050: Keycloak 3.4.3.Final (WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final) stopped in 7ms
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The file E:\backend\keycloak\modules\system\layers\base\org\wildfly\discovery\main\module.xml seems ok, even if it says

```
Unexpected content of type 'element start' named 'properties', text is: '<properties>' (position: START_TAG seen ...n:jboss:module:1.6" name="org.wildfly.discovery">\n    <properties>... @26:17)
```

Here is its exact content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
  ~ JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source.
  ~ Copyright 2016, Red Hat, Inc., and individual contributors
  ~ as indicated by the @author tags. See the copyright.txt file in the
  ~ distribution for a full listing of individual contributors.
  ~
  ~ This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
  ~ under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
  ~ published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of
  ~ the License, or (at your option) any later version.
  ~
  ~ This software is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  ~ but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  ~ MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
  ~ Lesser General Public License for more details.
  ~
  ~ You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
  ~ License along with this software; if not, write to the Free
  ~ Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA
  ~ 02110-1301 USA, or see the FSF site: http://www.fsf.org.
  -->

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.6" name="org.wildfly.discovery">
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.api" value="private"/>
    </properties>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="wildfly-discovery-client-1.0.0.Final.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.modules"/>
        <module name="org.wildfly.client.config"/>
        <module name="org.wildfly.common"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

It makes me mad for a few days now.
Has somebody please an idea ?

Thank you !

Seb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the version of JBoss Modules being used is too old and doesn't contain the schema for the 1.6.

```
10:05:11,459 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.1.Final
```

The `urn:jboss:module:1.6` isn't in the 1.5.x stream of JBoss Modules. You need at least 1.6.0.Final.

When I downloaded the standalone KeyCloak server 3.4.3 and booted I got 1.6.1.Final for the JBoss Modules version.

```
13:13:32,741 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.6.1.Final
13:13:32,932 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.7.SP1
13:13:33,032 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0049: Keycloak 3.4.3.Final (WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final) starting
```

It's possible you're trying to overlay KeyCloak on a version of WildFly that's too old.